# A question on group representation .

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

The problem is :

Prove or disprove : If $g$ and $h$ are two elements of a finite group $G$, then there exists a group $H$, an extension of $G$ such that $g$ and $h$ are conjugates in $H$.

Actually, I found on Wikipedia that it can be done using the HNN extension and Britton's lemma, it is a corollary of Britton's lemma, but the proof is not provided there.

Can someone please help me with the proof?

Comment: Did you mean to say, rather, that $g$ and $h$ have pre-images that are conjugate in $H$?

Comment: No, Sir, I want to say that g and h, currently being two elements of the newly extended group H must be conjugate to one another in H .

Answer (score 2):

Hint: conjugate elements have the same order. (Why?)

Comment: To runaway 44, but Sir, how can I have the extension H from G ???

Comment: It's a prove *or disprove* statement. Put some thought into the disprove possibility.

Comment: Yes Sir, conjugate elements have the same order but how to find an example that such an extension H may not always exist, I do merely know about group extension .

Comment: If two elements do not have the same order, they cannot be conjugate ... in any extension. So just find any group with two elements of different orders.